# System Monitor and free don't say the same

Tags: system-monitor

I use System Monitor to check free RAM:

[image: free ram]

But `free` don't say the same:

```
tuankiet65@UbuntuPC:~$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       8092368    7666932     425436          0     444560    3309676
-/+ buffers/cache:    3912696    4179672
Swap:      8370172     537836    7832336
```

So, which one is correct? System Monitor or `free`?

Comment: They both say the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Both. System Monitor consider buffers and cahced memory as free.

Cached – Here things get a little more confusing. This number does not include the Free portion of memory. And yet imight see that it is larger than the Available area of memory. That’s because Cached includes cache pages on both the “standby list” and what is called the “modified list.” Cache pages on the modified list have been altered in memory. No process has specifically asked for this data to be in memory, it is merely there as a consequence of caching. Therefore it can be written to disk at any time (not to the page file, but to its original file location) and reused. However, since this involves I/O, it is not considered to be “Available” memory.